# How do I run a javascript file in Objective-C?

Tags: javascript, ios, objective-c, webview

I have tried many things so far, and none have been successful. Is there a certain format the javascript file has to be in?
Thanks

Comment: What is your actual situation/goal (i.e., why do you want to run JavaScript code within your Objective-C application)? Without some additional context, you probably won't be able to get the answers you're looking for.

Comment: To use javasript in a UIWebView, the question is pretty much what I want to do. Run javascript from objecitve c

Answer (score 0):

**On Mac:**

Here is a reference to JavaScriptCore: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Carbon/Reference/WebKit_JavaScriptCore_Ref/_index.html. Also you may find "Integrate Javascript into Native Apps" video helpful on WWDC 2013.

**On iOS:**

The only scenario I can think of is to run UI Automation javascript using Instrument.

Answer (score 0):

The answer from @zyang relates to the javascript core - a perfectly good answer to the general question of 'how can i run javascript from objective-c'.

You indicate however that you want to use it in a UIWebView.

The (only) way that I am aware of doing this is to use the UIWebView class method [stringByEvaluatingJavascriptString](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIWebView_Class/Reference/Reference.html#jumpTo_29), which has an interface like this:

```
- (NSString *)stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:(NSString *)script
```

You pass the javascript you want to execute as the only parameter, and this will be executed in the UIWebView context, and return any result as an NSString.  I've used this to interact between the web and native code parts of a hybrid application.